# Capture is not updating and I can click on picturebox

Tags: c#, directx

I can't click on picture box. I am using the DirectX Capture class. I have a picture box and I cannot click on it now. So I have some event so I can draw a box and send those pix to a function and that works, but when I connect the picture box to the capture class, I can not longer click on my picture box. none of the events are working anymore.
here is my code :

```
 private void ConnectIR2BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                filters = new Filters();
                capture = new Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices[1], filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);

                capture.PreviewWindow = pictureBox1;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }

            capture.VideoSource = (Source)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
            capture.Cue();
            capture.Start();
            stateIndicatorComponent3.StateIndex = 3;
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }
```

also I do not think the image is updating.
what I am doing wrong ?
the events I am using are :
Paint
MouseDown
MouseMove
MouseUP

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a timer to update the picture box. Create a class for capture, then call that class in the timer. You do not have anything referring the timeframe it needs to update. Also be sure to enable the timer.

In your button event call the timer event.

Comment: ok so i use connect to my webcam and it is updating , but I still cannot get my events to work.

Comment: Are you creating a desktop recorder. I.e., the webcam overlay?

Comment: No, I am not. I am connecting to a EasyCAP that is connecting to a CamIR 1550 Cam from Scintacor.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well in example of the desktop recorder I can give you an example like I did. I access my webcam that way, but I use Aforge.net video .dll and I have never used what your using. However, there still has to be a timer so when you click the button it starts the capture. Anything you do as far as updating you use a timer or timer on a thread. You could also try this.refresh();